# How do I return all possible triplets in the 3Sum problem?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I am doing the 3Sum problem: https://leetcode.com/explore/interview/card/top-interview-questions-medium/103/array-and-strings/776/

Question in brief: Given an integer array nums, return all the triplets `[nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]]` such that `i != j`, `i != k`, and `j != k`, and `nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] == 0`.
Notice that the solution set must not contain duplicate triplets.

My problem: I have a solution which does return some but not all possible triplets, and I don't understand where I am going wrong. Secondly, my algorithm is O(N^2 log N), any recommendation on improving it is welcome.

```
Input:
[-1,0,1,2,-1,-4,-2,-3,3,0,4]
Output:
[[-3,-1,4],[-3,0,3],[-4,1,3],[-2,0,2],[-4,0,4]]
Expected:
[[-4,0,4],[-4,1,3],[-3,-1,4],[-3,0,3],[-3,1,2],[-2,-1,3],[-2,0,2],[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1]]
```

Algorithm: I have included my algorithm in the code along with comments, but here is the gist- For each pair of numbers I store their `sum` as a `key` and the indices of the numbers that give me that `sum` as the `value`. Then in a loop I go through each element and check if the difference between `target` value and that number is present as a `key` in the `map`. If it is, and all indices are unequal, I add it to a `vector` that is ultimately returned.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

vector<vector<int>> threeSum(vector<int> &nums) {
    /*
     * If less than 3 elements are passed return empty vector
     */
    if (nums.size() < 3)
        return {};

    int target = 0; // all three numbers sum up to 0 as given
    vector<vector<int>> outer; // this is returned by the function
    unordered_map<int, vector<int>> umap; // unordered_map for keeping sum and indices

    /*
     * Calculate sum of each pair of numbers
     * Store the sum as key and the pair as value
     * i != j is guaranteed
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.size(); j++)
            umap[nums[i] + nums[j]] = {i, j};

    /*
     * Go through each element and calculate the difference
     * between target and that element, this gives the sum
     * of the other two elements.
     * Look for the sum in unordered_map
     * If it is present check if all three indices are not equal to each other
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
        vector<int> inner;
        int diff = target - nums[i];
        auto it = umap.find(diff);
        inner = umap[diff];
        if (it != umap.end() && i != inner[0] && i != inner[1]) {
            inner.push_back(i);
            vector<int> tmp;
            for (auto &j: inner)
                tmp.push_back(nums[j]); // push actual numbers instead of indices
            sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.end()); // sort the inner three elements
            if (find(outer.begin(), outer.end(), tmp) == outer.end()) // for removing duplicates
                outer.push_back(tmp);
        }
    }
    return outer;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> v{-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4, -2, -3, 3, 0, 4};
    vector<vector<int>> ret = threeSum(v);
    for (auto &i: ret) {
        for (auto j: i)
            cout << j << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: *I have included my algorithm in the code* -- No, you wrote a program that you believe follows your algorithm.  That goes back to my first comment -- if your algorithm is sound, then maybe your code is not following it, and it's time to debug your code to see where it diverts from your algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Your bug is demonstrated with the input `[-5, 1, 2, 3, 4]`.

The problem is that `5 == 1+4 == 2+3`.  Your `map` will only store one of those pairs as the value for that key, and it therefore does not record the fact that BOTH pairs can lead to that key.

Answer (score 1):

The key idea is the same as the TwoSum problem. When we fix the 1st number, the 2nd and 3rd number can be found following the same reasoning as TwoSum.

The only difference is that the TwoSum problem of LEETCODE has a unique solution. However, in ThreeSum, we have multiple duplicate solutions that can be found. Most of the OLE errors happened here because you could've ended up with a solution with so many duplicates.

The naïve solution for the duplicates will be using the STL methods like below:

```
std::sort(res.begin(), res.end());
res.erase(unique(res.begin(), res.end()), res.end());
```

But, according to my submissions, this way will cause you to almost double your time consumption.

A better approach is to jump over the number which has been scanned, no matter if it is part of some solution or not.

If the three numbers formed a solution, we can safely ignore all the duplicates of them.

We can do this to all the three numbers such that we can remove the duplicates.

```
vector<vector<int> > threeSum(vector<int> &num) {
    
    vector<vector<int> > res;

    std::sort(num.begin(), num.end());

    for (int i = 0; i < num.size(); i++) {
        
        int target = -num[i];
        int front = i + 1;
        int back = num.size() - 1;

        while (front < back) {

            int sum = num[front] + num[back];
            
            // Finding answer which start from number num[i]
            if (sum < target)
                front++;

            else if (sum > target)
                back--;

            else {
                vector<int> triplet = {num[i], num[front], num[back]};
                res.push_back(triplet);
                
                // Processing duplicates of Number 2
                // Rolling the front pointer to the next different number forwards
                while (front < back && num[front] == triplet[1]) front++;

                // Processing duplicates of Number 3
                // Rolling the back pointer to the next different number backwards
                while (front < back && num[back] == triplet[2]) back--;
            }
            
        }

        // Processing duplicates of Number 1
        while (i + 1 < num.size() && num[i + 1] == num[i]) 
            i++;

    }
    
    return res;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for improvements how about this algorithm:

create an `std::unordered_map<int, int>` mapping each input to the number of occurances. Then:

```
for (const auto & it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ++it) {
    for (const auto & it2 = it; it2 != map.end(); ++it2) {
        auto it3 = map.find(-*it - *it2);
        if (it3 != map.end()) {
            it ((*it > *it3) || (*it2 > *it3)) continue;
            if (it == it2) {
                if (it == it3) {
                   if (it.second > 2) cout << *it << ", " *it2 << ", " << *it3 << std::endl;
                } else {
                   if (it.second > 1) cout << *it << ", " *it2 << ", " << *it3 << std::endl;
                }
            } else if (it2 == it3) {
                if (it2.second > 1) cout << *it << ", " *it2 << ", " << *it3 << std::endl;
            } else {
                cout << *it << ", " *it2 << ", " << *it3 << std::endl;
            }
        }             
    }
}
```

That should be `O(n^2)` without duplicates.

Comment: I was wondering if my algorithm is really `O(N^2 log N)` because the sorting step `sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.end()); // sort the inner three elements` that I am doing is really just sorting 3 elements each time ("triplets") so since it isn't scaling with the input at all, it should should still be be `O(N^2)`. I can simply use a couple of `if-else` statements instead so the call to `sort()` is avoided.

Comment: @DivyanshuVarma How does that help if your algorithm is simply wrong?

Comment: I wasn't talking about right or wrong, just something I had overlooked initially. BTW it would be helpful if you could explain your approach in words.

Comment: It builds all triplets with a sum of `0` were each number doesn't appear more often than in the input where `it <= it2` and `*it3` is the largest to avoid any duplicates.

Comment: `it ((*it > *it3) || (*it2 > *it3)) continue;` I think you meant `if`.

Comment: `if (it.second > 2) cout << *it << ", " *it2 << ", " << *it3 << std::endl;` When all iterators are equal, what does this do? It is also the only time you check for greater than 2.

Comment: There is only one way to have 3 times the same number and a sum of 0: `0, 0, 0`. If `0` was present more than twice in the input then `0, 0, 0` is printed.

Answer (score 0):

I did solve the problem, but it is inefficient and gives time limit exceeded on a few test cases.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

vector<vector<int>> threeSum(vector<int> &nums) {
    /*
     * If less than 3 elements are passed return empty vector
     */
    if (nums.size() < 3)
        return {};

    int target = 0; // all three numbers sum up to 0 as given
    vector<vector<int>> outer; // this is returned by the function
    unordered_multimap<int, vector<int>> umap; // unordered_map for keeping sum and indices

    /*
     * Calculate sum of each pair of numbers
     * Store the sum as key and the pair as value
     * i != j is guaranteed
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.size(); j++) {
            vector<int> temp;
            temp.push_back(i);
            temp.push_back(j);
            umap.emplace(make_pair(nums[i] + nums[j], temp));
        }

    /*
     * Go through each element and calculate the difference
     * between target and that element, this gives the sum
     * of the other two elements.
     * Look for the sum in unordered_map
     * If it is present check if all three indices are not equal to each other
     */
    //unordered_set<vector<int>> uset;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
        vector<int> inner;
        int diff = target - nums[i];
        auto it = umap.find(diff);
        while (it != umap.end()) {
            inner = it->second;
            if (it != umap.end() && i != inner[0] && i != inner[1]) {
                inner.push_back(i);
                //vector<int> tmp;
                //for (auto &j: inner)
                //    tmp.push_back(nums[j]); // push actual numbers instead of indices
                //sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.end()); // sort the inner three elements
                //if (find(outer.begin(), outer.end(), tmp) == outer.end()) // for removing duplicates
                outer.push_back(inner);

            }
            umap.erase(it);
            it = umap.find(diff);
        }
    }
    for (auto &i: outer)
        for (auto &j: i)
            j = nums[j];
    //sort(i.begin(),i.end());
    set<vector<int>> uset;
    for (auto &i: outer) {
        sort(i.begin(), i.end());
        uset.insert(i);
    }
    outer.clear();
    outer.insert(outer.end(), uset.begin(), uset.end());
    return outer;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> v{-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4, -2, -3, 3, 0, 4};
    vector<vector<int>> ret = threeSum(v);
    for (auto &i: ret) {
        for (auto j: i)
            cout << j << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var nums = [-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4];
// var nums = [0, 0, 0];

var threeSum = function (nums) {
  var result = [];
  if (nums.length > 3) {
    for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 2; j < nums.length; j++) {
        for (var k = 4; k < nums.length; k++) {
          if (i != j && i != k && j != k) {
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] == 0) {
              var ans = [nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]];
              result.push([...ans]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
  } else if (nums.every((item) => item === 0)) {
    result = [[...nums]];
    return result;
  } else {
    result = [];
    return result;
  }
};
console.log(threeSum(nums));
```